# “helps make exercising” OR “exercise”?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, causatives

I was asked to correct this sentence on my exam:

> A simple rule of 'five' helps make exercising a most enjoyable activity.

What's the error and how do I correct it?

On the exam I changed *exercising* to *exercise*, but now I'm having second thoughts.

Comment: Is this the exam question, or is this your answer and you want to know where you went wrong? What are your thoughts on how to answer this question? (We don't do homework: we'll help you do it, but to do that we need to know how far you've got with it.) Please edit the question to add in your work so far.

Comment: //A simple rule of 'five' helps make exercising a most enjoyable activity.Help one do; help me finish; help me // Was the intended sentence "A simple rule of 'five' helps exercising a most enjoyable activity", OR. "A simple rule of 'five' helps making exercises a most enjoyable activity"?

Comment: or should it be *'rule of five'* ?

Comment: @RamPillai - What are you trying to say? None of the things you’ve written are grammatical.

Comment: @Jim, I gave two options. a) A simple rule of 'five' helps exercising a most enjoyable activity. b) A simple rule of 'five' helps making exercises a most enjoyable activity.  My effort was to refine the author's example. Mistakes pointed out will be appreciated.

Comment: Both of your options are perfectly fine test ***questions*** But I think OP is looking for answers.

Comment: @Jim, Unless I misunderstood, these were corrected based on what the author wanted.

Comment: Ok, well, to correct your option A I'd probably go with "A simple rule ... helps exercising ***become*** a ..." and for B: " ... helps ***in*** making exercises a most ..."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sentence as it's written; it doesn't need to be corrected.